# jquery:Dialog box not poping in a dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a struts2-jsp application,i want a dialog pop up [image: dialog pop up] whenever edit hyperlink in clicked,I am using Jquery to pop up a dialog when Edit hyperlink is clicked.
The problem is that Dialog box pops up only when the first edit is clicked,in the second and other edits which are generated dynamically when a record is added dialog box doesn't pops up.

The Jquery code is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#todo" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#dialogLink" ).click(function() {
$( "#todo" ).dialog('open');
});
});
</script>
```

The code to dynamically generate the table is:

```
<div class="content">
        <table class="todoTable" cellpadding="5px">
             <tr class=even>
                <th>TITLE</th>
                <th>STATUS</th>
                <th>EDIT</th>
                <th>DELETE</th>
            </tr>

           <!--This will iterate through the todolist -->
            <s:iterator value="gettodoList()" status="todoStatus">

                <tr class="<s:if test="#todoStatus.odd == true ">odd</s:if> <s:else>even</s:else>">

                    <td><s:property value="title" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="complete" /></td>

                    <!-- This will append the Id with the url -->
                    <td> 
                    <a id="dialogLink" href="#">Edit</a> 
                    </td>
                    <td><s:url id="deleteURL" action="deleteTodo">
                                    <s:param name="id" value="%{id}">                       </s:param>
                        </s:url> <s:a href="%{deleteURL}">Delete</s:a>
                   </td>
               </tr>
            </s:iterator>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

[image: client side html is]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: also `id` can not be duplicated in single document. Try giving then a `class` instead of `id` and bind event via event delegation technique.

Comment: make sure that jquery code is executed after updating the table. perhaps the jquery code is executed only once at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.on()` to set the event handler instead of the `.click()` as the latter will only attach the event on existing nodes while the first will attach it to existing nodes and new ones as well similar to how `.live()` used to work in earlier versions of jquery

take a look at http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: i used the .on()  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#todo" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#dialogLink" ).on("click",(function() {
$( "#todo" ).dialog('open');
}));
});
</script>   
But still dialog box is poping up for first edit hyperlink

Comment: since you are setting all of the iterated items with the same ID this will happen, either give them diffrent IDs or set a class instead

Comment: dynamically creating id for each anchor tag worked for me

Answer (score 0):

1) it is because you are using an `id`, use a `class` and it should work fine.

&
2) you should try to use `on()` for dynamically generated elements.